# Group By - Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem.

In SQL, when I do something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Fruits GROUP BY fruitName;
```

I can have something like:

```
ID FRUITNAME PRICE
1  Apple     $5.00
4  Banana    $3.00
6  Mango     $5.00
```

How can convert that, to Linq with Lambda? I tried `.GroupBy()`, but only groups with a Key (fruitName) in another object, example:

```
Apple
 1 $5.00
 2 $6.00
 3 $6.00
Banana
 4 $3.00
 5 $2.00
Mango
 6 $5.00
```

May you help me? thanks!

**UPDATE:**

[In MySQL this is the logic that I used, and it works without problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v61gx.png)

Comment: Your SQL will not generate your expected output. Once you get the correct SQL, it's almost identical (logically) for LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have "something like" the table above from such a query. Your SQL query would crash and burn because you're selecting columns (`id` and `price`) that don't appear in the `group by` clause.

What are you actually trying to do?

It looks like you're trying to get the `Fruit` with the lowest `id` in its respective group when grouped by `fruitName`.

In which case, something like:

```
fruits
  .GroupBy(fr => fr.fruitName)
  .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(fr => fr.Id).First())
```

would do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I can have "something like", at least in mysql, try it ;) anyway, thanks! looks like your answer is good, I did it in another way minutes before, I will post it. Thanks again!

Comment: @LLeon Wow... mysql really does that? I wouldn't rely on this as the row selection behaviour is documented as indeterminate. Will your grouped apple be $5 or $6? You should read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). They're both highly relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the links! and in this case, for example, I only want to show principal fruit (apple) and when user click on it, displays its varieties (Red, Green, Golden, etc), that's why I don't take careful of the order, because it's irrelevant (obviously, in my example, maybe in another example will be necessary specified the order). Of course the sql logic could be better (many to one SQL relation), but I only use it to learn a little more of LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this form:

```
   fruits.
    GroupBy(p => p.idFruit,
               p => p.fruitName,
               (key, g) => new {
                   idFruit = key,
                   fruitName= g.ToList().FirstOrDefault()
               }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use group by you need to aggregate all of the other columns, like max min ...etc. otherwise sql query will not execute.

in C# side, it's slightly different, cause you can produce the same sql or you can aggregate in memory, after pulling all of the records.

EX: LINQ format:

```
from f in fruits
group by f.fruitName into g
select new{
fruit= f.fruitName,
price= g.Max() // or whatever selector to grab one of the prices.
}
```

Method groups will look like:

```
fruits.GroupBy(f=> f.fruitName).Select(f=> new {
   fruit= f.Key,
   price= f.MAx() // or any other wat to select one of the prices
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Tuple<string, int>> Fruits = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
        Fruits.Add(Tuple.Create("Apple", 10));
        Fruits.Add(Tuple.Create("Apple", 5));
        Fruits.Add(Tuple.Create("Apple", 20));
        Fruits.Add(Tuple.Create("Mango", 10));
        Fruits.Add(Tuple.Create("Orange", 10));
        Fruits.Add(Tuple.Create("Mango", 20));
        Fruits.Add(Tuple.Create("Orange", 12));

        foreach (var item in Fruits.GroupBy(s => s.Item1))
        {
            string FruitName = item.Key;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var price in item)
                sb.Append(price.Item2 + ", ");

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Fruit Name :{0} Prices :{1}", FruitName, sb.ToString().Trim(new char[] { ',', ' ' })));
        }

   output:
 Fruit Name :Apple Prices :10, 5, 20
 Fruit Name :Mango Prices :10, 20
 Fruit Name :Orange Prices :10, 12
```